# save input from text file to array

Tags: java, file, text, arrays

How to save text file content to different arrays?

my text file content is like this;

```
12 14 16 18 13 17 14 18 10 23
pic1 pic2 pic3 pic4 pic5 pic6 pic7 pic8 pic9 pic10
left right top left right right top top left right
100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000
```

how can I save each line into different array?
e.g.

```
line 1 will be saved in an array1
line 2 will be saved in an array2
line 3 will be saved in an array3
line 4 will be saved in an array4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
List<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>(); //You need an array list of arrays since you dont know how many lines does the text file has
try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infilename"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
           String arr[] = str.split(" ");
           if(arr.length>0) arrays.add(arr);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

At the end  arrays will contain every array. In your example `arrays.length()==4`

To iterate over the arrays:

```
for( String[] myarr : arrays){
   //Do something with myarr
}
```

**Solution 2: I don't think this is a good idea but if you are sure the file always is going to contain 4 lines you can do this**

```
String arr1[];
String arr2[];
String arr3[];
String arr4[];
try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infilename"));
        String str;
        str = in.readLine();
        arr1[] = str.split(" ");
        str = in.readLine();
        arr2[] = str.split(" ");
        str = in.readLine();
        arr3[] = str.split(" ");
        str = in.readLine();
        arr4[] = str.split(" ");

        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I mean is that the every line will be saved in different array. e.g. I will have 4 different arrays with the sizes of 10 each. Not in the same array.

Comment: e.g. there are 4 lines in the txt file
will create 4 arrays.
each array will have the size if 10.

and each elements on the array can be called as e.g. array1.get(i)

Comment: I have updated the answer to iterate over the 4 arrays.
Are you always going to have 4 arrays?

Comment: THANK YOU.. yes the text file will always contained 4 lines..:-)

Answer (score 1):

look at String[] split